# Как переключаться между окнами в vim/ nerdtree

Tags: vim

Всем привет, не мог найти в документаций как переключаться между вкладками в Neovim в плагине NerdTree, на фотке выделил красным. Спасибо всем кто откликнется.[image: Вот]

Comment: gt уже отменили? Если это у фвас вкладки

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, добрый вы человек.

Comment: Если что, есть ещё gT в обратную сторону. Да, у Вас ка то странно nerdtree открыт, обычно он "сбоку". Но это вим. Если так удобно, то пусть будет так